# progress 4gl :i want to avoid error messages while running the program

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttservice NO-UNDO
    FIELD ad-num AS CHARACTER
    INDEX ttprimary AS UNIQUE ad-num .

ASSIGN  ttservice.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num NO-ERROR
```

In this, how to avoid error messages when i am adding duplicate records,
situation is:

when i try to add the duplicate records in temp table it doesnot accept,it is ok ,but it display error messages while running a program,iwant to suppres that error messages.,and avoid the duplicate adding records

Comment: Your example is woefully incomplete.  You have no logic that creates records -- how can you need to avoid duplication errors when you are not creating anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the existence of a duplicate key before you try to create it.

(Filling in the blanks.)

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttservice NO-UNDO
    FIELD ad-num AS CHARACTER  /* you have a "num" field defined as character?  that's misleading  */
    INDEX ttprimary AS UNIQUE ad-num .

for each vehicle no-lock:  /* perhaps ad-num is non-unique in the vehicle table? */

  find ttservice where ttservice.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num no-error.
  if available ttservice then
    do:
      message "oops!".  /* or whatever it is you want when a duplicate occurs... */
    end.
   else
    do:
      create ttservice.
      ASSIGN  ttservice.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num.
    end.

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to get unique ad-num values from the vehicles table:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttservice NO-UNDO
    FIELD ad-num AS CHARACTER
    INDEX ttprimary AS UNIQUE ad-num .

FOR EACH vehicles NO-LOCK
    BREAK BY vehicles.ad-num:

    IF FIRST-OF(vehicles.ad-num) THEN
        DO:
        CREATE ttservice.
        ASSIGN ttservice.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num.
        END.

END.
```

Answer (score 0):

Two valued answers have already been added by great professionals but i would like to add mine with minor changes.

> ```
> def TEMP-TABLE ttservice NO-UNDO
>     FIELD iservid AS INT
>     INDEX tt-primary AS UNIQUE iservid.
>
> VEHICLELOOP:
> for each vehicles use-index <index-name>
> NO-LOCK:
>
>     IF CAN-FIND(first ttservice
>                 where ttservice.iservid = vehicles.iservid)
>     THEN
>         NEXT VEHICLELOOP.
>     ELSE DO:
>         create ttservice.
>         ASSIGN ttservice.iservid = vehicles.iservid.
> END. /* VEHICLELOOP */
> ```

Answer (score 0):

So I read the answers and think they're sufficient to fix your particular issue. But here's the general way of thinking you should assume when coding for Progress OpenEdge:

Adding no-error to statements (when they allow it) will "suppress errors", though sometimes they're inevitable and suppressing does no good to the stability of your application, always think of treating them (and displaying errors is a part of this).
Whether you choose to check for existence of a record prior to creation or just set your query to not iterate for undesired (repeated) records is up to you. I advise you to check for performance with different approaches (especially in doing a for each for a large table) to see which one is more satisfactory.

So here's my personal suggestion:

```
for each vehicles no-lock:
    if can-find(first ttService where ttService.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num) then      
       next.
    create ttService.
    assign ttService.ad-num = vehicles.ad-num no-error.
    if error-status:error then 
       message "Something went horribly wrong:" + error-status:get-message(1) 
           view-as alert-box error.
end.
```

In my example above, the error will only be shown if the assign actually fails. It is not likely to happen, I just wanted to show how the usage of no-error (and its treatment) works.
Anyway, hope it helps!